# Streaming mp3 files in Django through Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, http-headers, uwsgi

I have a website based on Django framework. I am running website via Nginx webserver (uWSGI,Django,Nginx). I want to stream mp3 files on my website with Accept-Ranges header. I want to serve my mp3 files with Nginx. I need my API to look like this

```
http://192.168.1.105/stream/rihanna
```

This must return mp3 file with partial download (Accept-Ranges).
My mp3 files are stored in : /home/docker/code/app/media/data/
When I run the server with these configurations and browse to 192.168.1.105/stream/rihanna , Django returns 404.

My Nginx conf:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
server unix:/home/docker/code/app.sock; # for a file socket
# server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
# the port your site will be served on, default_server indicates that this server block
# is the block to use if no blocks match the server_name
listen      80 default;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
# the domain name it will serve for
server_name .example.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
charset     utf-8;

# max upload size
client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

# Django media
location /media  {
    autoindex       on;
    sendfile        on;
    sendfile_max_chunk      1024m;
    internal;
    #add_header X-Static hit;
    alias /home/docker/code/app/media/;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
}
location /static {
    alias /home/docker/code/app/static/; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
}

# Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
location / {

    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /home/docker/code/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

My views.py :

```
def stream(request, offset):
     try:

            mp3_path = os.getcwd() + '/media/data/' + offset + '.mp3'
            mp3_data = open(mp3_path, "r").read()



except:
    raise Http404()





response = HttpResponse(mp3_data, content_type="audio/mpeg", status=206)
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = mp3_path
response['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(mp3_path)
response['Content-Dispostion'] = "attachment; filename=" + mp3_path
response['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'
```

I want Nginx serve this files. And I really need Accept-Ranges enabled.

My Settings.py :

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR =   os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.105', '0.0.0.0']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'beats.urls'

 TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'beats.wsgi.application'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')




# Database


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
   }
}


# Password validation


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':   'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My problem is: It doesn't work, and Django return 404 Error webpage.

Comment: Does Django needs to be able to actually control who can see the files? If not just put them into your static file directory and let Nginx handle the streaming. You'll get much better performance as well.

Comment: @AndréBorie Thank you. My admin files are in /static/ path. When I want to browse to them,Nginx returns 404. I really don't know why. Nginx return 404 error even on static path of my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I did not copy the Nginx configuration file to the available-sites path. And because of it, It didn't work.

And in my views.py:

```
response = HttpResponse(mp3_data, content_type="audio/mpeg", status=206)
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = mp3_path
```

these 2 lines must be changed to:

```
response= HttpResponse('', content_type="audio/mpeg", status=206)
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/media/data/' + file_name + '.mp3'
```